# Using Ifs and Min together, returning a different number depending on lowest value in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

I have a column that will contain several numbers (between 1-4) in each cell depending on answers from a survey. ie 1,2,3,4 or 3,4 or 1,2,3

In a separate column i need to have just one single number, which, because the answers escalate means that i just need the lowest value returned. Ie if 1,2,3,4, i need 1. If 3,4 i want to return 3.

From what i understand, I could do this easily enough using the MIN function. However due how the question was asked, if the responds lowest number was 1, I need to enter a 4 into the database, If 2 than 3, 3 than 2, and 4 than 1.

My thought was to use several IF statements that IF the MIN value = 1, than return 4 etc. However, I'm not sure if this is the most effective way to go about it.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I assume that your 1,2,3,4 is a string. If it is a string then this is long winded but should work; you could nest IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(1,[CELL])),4, IF(repeat search for 2 returning 3 etc.

Comment: For the example you provided, the formula `=IFERROR(5-VALUE(LEFT(TRIM(A1);1));"")` returns the correct result

Comment: @RickyTillson thanks so much for this, I've run this and it works!

Comment: @JohnSUN, thanks for your response also, greatly appreciated! I think i need to take a look at those functions to understand what is going on, but thanks for giving me somethign to learn!

Comment: I think in your case you can use use `switch` or `choose` as a substitute for nested `if` or `ifs`. The unknown to me is if you have a response of `1,2,3` is the translated value supposed to be 4 or 3?

Comment: Your conditions are not very clear, it is best to briefly describe the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

[**TRIM function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/trim-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9) - Use TRIM on text that you have received from another application that may have irregular spacing.

For example, if " 1,2" was entered into a cell by mistake (with a space before 1), then after processing with the LEFT() function, we will get the correct string "1,2" (without extra space)

[**LEFT**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/left-leftb-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c) returns the first character or characters in a text string

So, LEFT("1,2";1) return "1" (as string)

[**VALUE function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/value-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2) converts a text string that represents a number to a number.

Now subtract this number from 5: `5-1=4`, `5-2=3`, etc.

If nothing is entered in the cell, an error will occur. To avoid displaying an error, wrap the entire expression in an [**IFERROR function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)

```
=IFERROR(5-VALUE(LEFT(TRIM(A1);1));"")
```